# Trouble with SQL joins and relational tables

Tags: sql, join, relational-database

Hope you can help. I am attempting to pull data from a ratings table that I have set up but I'm having a hard time coming up with the code to do it that works.

Here is my table layout with relevant columns:

**inah_topic**:

```
topicID    |    topicName
--------------------------------
```

**inah_qoptions**:

```
optionID   |   questionID    |   Option   |  OptionValue
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**inah_question**:

```
questionID |    Question
---------------------------
```

**inah_rating**:

```
ID    |  userID  |  topicId  |  QuestionID  |  optionValue
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to do is to tally the results for each question for each topic.

Each topic will has the same set of ratings (questions) For example: Ease of Entrance with multiple options[value] (easy =1, moderate=2, hard=3)

So when a user goes in to each topic they will rate each of a dozen or so questions.

So topic "photography = 1" may be rated "easy = 1" for question "ease of entrance=1" by user=1 or may be rated moderate = 2 ease of entrance by another user.

So when on the topic page, I need to separate the results for each topic.

That is easy enough with a `Select * from inah_rating where topicid= $topicId`

But I am having trouble figuring out the query and additional code to count the results of each result separately.

I believe I need a foreach set, but I'm not sure how to set it up from a query

Basically, count each $ovalue per each unique question ID

Ideally, the query should also `Join` with the question and question-options tables to replace the ID values with the actual question or option names.

I hope that makes sense. If not, i will create some sample data. Thanks

EDIT: Here is some sample data so I can better explain the results I am trying to achieve.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znjH4.png)

The data was sorted in excel to make it easy to see the relations

I also included only one topic id but there will be an unlimited number of topics. So for this data set, after sorting by topic Id, i need to separate by questionID to produce a result like this.

Question 3 from topic 1, has 3 people who answered "2", 2 people answered "3", and 2 people answered "4", while only one person answered question 5 with option "3"

This data will be used first to display the result with the majority, but also used to display an overall graph of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your schema, for counting the number of results for a particular topic, you can do by grouping your rating table by questionid and then projecting out count(*) along with questionid. Something likes below,

```
SELECT COUNT (*), questionID
FROM inah_rating
WHERE inah_rating.topicid = $topicId
GROUP BY questionID
```

And if you want to count results for each topic too, then you can group by topicId too. Something likes below,

```
SELECT COUNT (*), questionID, topicId
FROM inah_rating
WHERE inah_rating.topicid = $topicId
GROUP BY questionID, topicId
```

However, if you want to project columns from other tables like questions and topic. Then, you need to join with these respective tables.

Comment: I think this would simply count the number of questions wouldn't it? I included some more information to better explain the results I am trying to achieve.